# Codeigniter->Foundation->Dropdown Não funciona

Tags: codeigniter, dropdown, zurb-foundation

Bom dia, sou iniciante na programação *web* e estou enfrentando alguns problemas em um curso de vídeo aulas (fornecido pela empresa, um pouco desatualizado) que estou fazendo.

Cheguei a um ponto no qual não consigo progredir... Tenho de executar um menu com um *Dropdown*... e não estou conseguindo...

Agradeço quem conseguir me ajudar!

```
<!doctype html>

<html class="no-js" lang="pt-br" dir="ltr">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><?php if(isset($titulo)): ?>{titulo} | <?php endif; ?>{titulo_padrao}</title>
    {headerinc}
    </head>
  <body>
        <?php if(esta_logado(FALSE)): ?>
            <div class="row header">
                <div class="eigth columns">
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url('painel');?>"><h1>Painel ADM</h1></a>
                </div>  
                <div class="four columns">
                    <p class="text-right">Logado como <strong><?php echo $this->session->userdata('user_nome'); ?></strong></p>
                    <p class="text-right">
                        <?php echo anchor('usuario/alterar_senha/'.$this->session->userdata('user_id'), 'Alterar senha', 'class="button radius tiny"'); ?>
                        <?php echo anchor('usuario/logoff/', 'Sair', 'class="button radius tiny alert"'); ?>
                    </p>
                </div>              
            </div>

@Este é o código que estou tentando trabalhar em cima para funcionar.


        <div class="row">
            <div class="top-bar">
              <div class="top-bar-left">
                <ul class="dropdown menu" >
                  <li><?php echo anchor('painel', 'Inicio'); ?></li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown menu" >Usuários</a>
                    <ul class="class="dropdown menu">
                      <li><?php echo anchor('usuarios/cadastra', 'Cadastrar')?></li>
                      <li><?php echo anchor('usuarios/gerenciar', 'Gerenciar')?></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>                  
        </div></div>

@Este seria o meu código original.

            <!--div class="row">
                <div class="twelve columns menu-site">
                    <ul class="nav-bar">
                        <li><?php echo anchor('painel', 'Inicio'); ?></li>
                            <li class="has-flyout">
                                <?php echo anchor('usuarios/gerenciar', 'Usuarios'); ?>
                                <ul class="flyout">
                                    <li><?php echo anchor('usuarios/cadastra', 'Cadastrar')?></li>
                                    <li><?php echo anchor('usuarios/gerenciar', 'Gerenciar')?></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>                       
                    </ul>                   
                </div>
            </div-->
        <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="row paineladm">
            {conteudo}  
    </div>
    <script src="js/foundation.mim.js"></script>

        <div class="row rodape">
            <div class"twelve columns">
                <div class="text-center">{rodape}</div>
            </div>
        </div>

            {footerinc}
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: mas o que você não está conseguindo? O que nesse menu com dropdown você não conseguiu fazer? O Dropdown? O php no menu?

Comment: O meu está aparecendo!
Mas os Subs-menus com a seta do lado não está...

A intenção é fazer uma barra de menu com dois obejetos:

| Inicio |  |Usuarios | 

E dentro do Inicio, dropdown com:

| Cadastrar |
| Gerenciar |